# Truncate the text for long items in an md-select drop-down

Tags: javascript, angular-material

Is it possible to truncate the text of a selected item within an md-select statement such that it fits within the allocated space?
The only behavior I can get is that the full text of the item selected is always displayed.

I created an example of my problem on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QymLwr

Thanks!

```
<html ng-app="playground">
  <head>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css"></link>
  </head>
  <body layout-align="center center" layout="column" ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <md-select ng-model="name"  style="width: 200px;" placeholder="Choose">
      <md-option>This is a very long text that when selected flows outside of the available space and is not truncated</md-option>
      <md-option>Option 2</md-option>
      <md-option>Option 3</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </body>
</html>


angular.module('playground', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apparently is a bug is already demonstrated at https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6312
A workaround is also described there that works well for me, i.e. the following CSS:

```
.md-select-value *:first-child { 
  width: calc(100% - 24px); 
}
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GodRXP for an updated codepen.

Comment: :) great works very fine for me in Angular.js

Answer (score 2):

Make a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

> ## $filter
>
> ---
>
> **In HTML Template Binding**
>
> `{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}`
>
> **In JavaScript**
>
> `$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)`
>
> ---
>
> via: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

---

#### Screenshot:

[image: ss]

#### Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPeMpd?editors=1010

#### Markup with filter set to `15` characters:

```
<md-option>{{myLongString | truncate:15}}</md-option>
```

#### `truncate` Filter:

```
// Filter below found here: http://jsfiddle.net/tuyyx/

app.filter('truncate', function() {
  return function(text, length, end) {
    if (isNaN(length))
      length = 10;

    if (end === undefined)
      end = "...";

    if (text.length <= length || text.length - end.length <= length) {
      return text;
    } else {
      return String(text).substring(0, length - end.length) + end;
    }

  };
});
```

Comment: Add if(text!=undefined) to avoid error (in some cases)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in CSS.

```
md-option {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of setting overflow. With this I have been able to search more specifically for the problem and it seems that this is a known bug in the current code. The bug is demonstrated at https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6312 and a workaround is described there that works well for me, i.e. the following CSS: .md-select-value *:first-child {
  width: calc(100% - 24px);
}

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me just by using CSS

```
.customTruncatedText {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```